# Laptop WIFI attack insecure

Tags: wifi

If a laptop has WIFI but it is disabled in the Device Manager, can it still be used to gain access to the machine?

Comment: Generally, no. An intelligence agency might, but any other attacker will need you to enable internet.

Comment: Your question is too general. With physical access or if the machine has already been compromised, then the adapter can be re-enabled at any time.

Comment: To save power, my internal wifi adaptor stops receiving power once it is disabled by the device manager. So even if it contains vulnerable network stack, it can't be exploited locally or remotely.